# Javascript Value Manipulation In Hidden Field

Tags: javascript, dom

I want a particular set of values splitted by "^" deleted from a hidden field 
I am putting value in hidden fields. Now I want particular values set deleted, i.e.

HIDDEN FIELD VALUE = 1|1|1|1^2|2|2|2^3|3|3|3

DROP DOWN=
INDEX |VALUE  | TEXT
  0   | 1     |1
  1   | 2     |2
  2   | 3     |3

WANT TO DELETE = ^2|2|2|2 WITH DROPDOWN VALUE 2;

Here is my code showing how I put values in the hidden field

```
function putinactions()
{

    var hiddenfield = document.getElementById("hdfActions");
    var ActList= document.getElementById("Actionlist");

     var attdt= document.getElementById("txtAttOn");
     var depen= document.getElementById("ddlDepend");
     var tattby= document.getElementById("txtAttendedBy");
     var dattby= document.getElementById("ddlAttendedBy");
     var dpriority= document.getElementById("ddlPriority");
     var taction= document.getElementById("txtAction");
     var dstatus= document.getElementById("ddlStatus");
     var tacdt= document.getElementById("txtACDt");
    if(depen.value==9)
    {
       tattby.value = "0";
    }

      if(depen.value!=9)
    {
       dattby.value = "0";
    }

    if(hiddenfield.value=="")
        {
            hiddenfield.value=
                        attdt.value+"|"+ 
                        depen.value+"|"+
                        tattby.value+"|"+
                        dattby.value+"|"+
                        dpriority.value+"|"+
                        taction.value+"|"+
                       dstatus.value+"|"+
                       tacdt.value;
        }

   else
           {

            hiddenfield.value=hiddenfield.value+"^"+
                        attdt.value+"|"+ 
                        depen.value+"|"+
                        tattby.value+"|"+
                        dattby.value+"|"+
                        dpriority.value+"|"+
                        taction.value+"|"+
                       dstatus.value+"|"+
                       tacdt.value;
           }

            var optn = document.createElement("OPTION"); 
            optn.text=attdt.value+"~~"+taction.value.substring(0,20)+"...";
            optn.value=taction.value;
            ActList.options.add(optn);
        attdt.value="";
        depen.value="";

          taction.value="";
          tacdt.value="";
}
```

Comment: OK, OK we hear you, no need to shout.

Comment: @Anas Khan: Please do not use capital letters as if you are shouting to us. It is better if you can put some time to elaborate the issue and review your language if it can present what you wish to tell others. Your post is not yet very clear of what you wish to achieve or the problem you are facing.

Comment: oh sorry for that i aint shouting i just forgot to off caps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in removing the values enclosed by ^ characters, you can simply use a regular expression.

Comment: i Did that REGEXP but it aint work properly i 've changed the value but not changing all the way

Comment: Did you try debugging the script?

Comment: yes i did i put alerts all the time it going prefect but when i use hidden feild in .cs page it remains the same as before putting regExp

Comment: You might not be able to change the hidden fields in ASP.NET page.

Comment: sir when i modified the whole value by then its working properly but when i split and filtered and then modified on particular value then it aint working :(

Comment: @AnasKhan: Can you share the code that you used to change the content of the hidden field?